# Does the implementation of an abstract method in Java needs throws someException declaration if the abstract method has it?

Tags: java, exception, abstract-methods

In the superclass I have:

```
abstract someMethod() throws someException;
```

In the subclass I have:

```
someMethod(){/*do something*/}
```

Is it ok to do this without a `throws someException` declaration? Is it that the `throws someException` declaration is there by default without adding it explicitly?

Comment: If an implementation doesn't throw an exception, it doesn't have to declare it. Not explicitly or implicitly.

Comment: This question falls squarely into the "try it and see if it works" category.  Or in this case, "try it and see if it compiles".

Comment: @Dawood, I known it compiles, only don't know it compiles because the `throws exception` is add automatically or not necessary.

Answer (score 7):

Your implementation doesn’t have to throw any exceptions. However, it can *only* throw checked exceptions specified in the abstract class.